# Implicit memory allocation and initialization when declaring a pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, declaration, allocation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Declaring a pointer to struct in C++ automatically allocates memory for its members. Am I wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9421938/declaring-a-pointer-to-struct-in-c-automatically-allocates-memory-for-its-memb)

Say if I define the structure Human as:

```
struct Human{int year, Human* Mom};
```

does the expression

```
Human* Bob;
```

**automatically allocate a memory** for both Bob and the Human object it is pointing to?
Because I noticed that

```
Bob == NULL
```

is false;
Does this mean that the above expression creates a static memory of the object Human?

Also, I noticed that

```
Bob->year
```

is NOT initialized to 0 automatically, but

```
Bob->Mom
```

is being initialized to NULL, why is that?

**Another thing,** if I allocate the memory dynamically, e.g.

```
Human* Bob = new Human;
```

Then I found that

```
Bob->Mom
```

is no longer NULL, how this is happening?

Comment: `Bob` is uninitialized. It's pointless trying to figure out what it's doing with it.

Comment: -1 The code as given, e.g. `struct Human{int year, Human* Mom};`, won't compile and is **not the real code**.

Comment: you should find those basic and simple question in books, not there.

Comment: @chris: because it's syntactically invalid. the code you are linking to is not the posted the code, but some other code. why are you linking to some other code, pretending that that's the OP's code, if not for trolling.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf, Sorry, I just realized there was a comma in there. I typed the short sample up myself rather than switch back and copy-paste. I do see your point. At first I thought you meant the `Human *Mom;` part, so my test was checking that.

Answer (score 1):

At minimum, the structure declaration should be corrected to:

```
struct Human { int year; Human *Mom; };
```

The statement:

```
Human *Bob;
```

then creates a storage location, but does not initialize it if it is created inside a function.  If it is at global scope, it would be initialized to zero (NULL), but you say `Bob == NULL` is false, so it must be an uninitialized local variable.  It doesn't point at anything.  Any use of it other than as the target for an assignment invokes undefined behaviour because the value in `Bob` is undefined.

No; the definition shown does not allocate storage for `Bob` to point at.

Your other observations all depend on the quirks of your runtime system.  Because the behaviour is undefined, anything can happen and it is 'OK' according to the standard.  You need a default constructor for the type to get the values set sensibly when you use:

```
Human *Bob = new Human;
```

You have not provided one, and the system doesn't need to provide one, so the object pointed at is uninitialized.

Answer (score 0):

Its your responsibility to initialize pointer values. Unless you have set them to something (like `0` or `NULL`), their value is undefined and you may get a different uninitialized pointer value with each corresponding allocation.

In terms of allocation, you have defined a recursive or self-referential data structure. Consider what happens if it in fact did allocate memory for an additional Human for the `Mom` member; it would then have to allocate another Human for `Bob->Mom->Mom` and so on...

So, no. Only one `Human` is allocated. Any native pointer is just a memory address location, nothing more.

You can make pointer initialization easier on yourself if you use a constructor:

```
struct Human { 
    int year; 
    Human *Mom; 
    Human() : year(0), Mom(NULL) {}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it doesn't allocate memory. Bob is a pointer with garbage value, so who knows what it's pointing to.

Comment: You got chapter/verse for that?  I can't find "garbage value" anywhere in the standard.

Comment: @CrazyEddie, Genesis 1:1: *In the beginning, there was garbage.*

Comment: Undefined. See 6.2.4 http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf

Answer (score 0):

> does the expression Human* Bob; automatically allocate a memory for both Bob and the Human object it is pointing to? Because I noticed that Bob==NULL is false; Does this mean that the above expression creates a static memory of the object Human?

No, it doesn't. Bob is not initialised, so will just point to some random garbage. You must explicitly allocate memory for Bob.

> Another thing, if I allocate the memory dynamically, e.g. Human* Bob=new Human; Then I found that Bob->Mom is no longer NULL, how this is happening?

As above, uninitialised memory could have anything in it. Trying to follow the pointer will lead to disaster. Good practice is to initialise all pointers to `NULL` or to immediately point them at an allocated block of memory.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the only instruction you have given to the compiler is to create a pointer (either a 32 bit or 64 bit variable) which you intend to point to a structure of type "Human".

Since you have not initialized the pointer, its value is most likely what was in that memory space - that could be a 0 (NULL), or anything else.

When you call Bob->Mom, you are dereferencing the pointer (Bob) and looking at an area in memory that is arbitrary (potentially a space you are not allowed access to). You most likely will get a segmentation fault (on a *nix machine).

What you should do is:

```
Human* Bob = new Human();
```

That will create dedicated space for the structure and return the address of that structure and assign it to the pointer Bob. Now, when you dereference Bob, it will actually point to a space which has been allocated specifically for the Human structure.